# Initial state from server in parent component

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

I am checking out the [ngrx example app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/v4.1.1/example-app) and trying to figure out a good way to initialize state on the find page (http://localhost:4200/#/books/find).

It seemed like I should be able to add this to the AppComponent

```
ngOnInit() { 
    this.store.dispatch(new book.Search('Michael Jordan')); 
}
```

but that is not populating the store in the `FindBookPageComponent`
it seems like it happens too early in the chain.
Wondering if someone can explain this and offer a better way.

Note:
Adding the ngOnInit to the `FindBookPageComponent` works but it would get called every time the person navigates back. I would like this to be more of a initial state if that makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to put it in router guards => canActivate()

check for data exists or not in store; else dispatch the load data

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.checkStore().pipe(
    switchMap(() => of(true)),
    catchError((error) => of(false))
    );
}

checkStore(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.store.select(fromStore.getDataLoaded).pipe(
    tap(loaded => {
      if (!loaded) {
        this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadDataCollection());
      }
    }),
    filter(loaded => loaded),
    take(1)
    );
}
```

Comment: Related, you could use a route resolver: https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/